# Is it OK for Interviewer not to enable their webcam during a job video Interview

Tags: interviewing

I was interviewed a couple of times recently and both interviewers wouldn't enable their web cam after they tell me to enable mine.

Isn't this rude?

Comment: Did you ask them why? I can think of a variety of reasons.

Comment: Indeed. The webcam in my work laptop is disabled (by me). Mostly for security, but also because I'm not a fan of my video being accidentally broadcast when I join a webex (or similar) meeting with different default settings.

Comment: I can guarantee that the way I disabled it will not allow it to be turned back on.

Comment: This happened to me recently.  The interviewer "couldn't get the webcam to work" but seemed so non-chalant about it and said *Well let's just proceed and I'm sure we'll forget about it shortly.*  When I asked we do it by phone instead, he seemed dismayed, leading me to believe this was routine and a standard practice.  Maybe someone could shed light on to **why** interviewers want this asymmetry?

Comment: It's certainly a little bit odd. At the very least it creates a strange interview environment from the get go, it is simply not a normal social interaction where only one person can see the other.

Comment: Even if we assume rudeness rather than tech problems, it's still up to you to decide whether you want the job enough to give them the benefit of the doubt. You could of course have brought it up at the time and offered to reschedule, or to turn off your own camera, if the asymmetry really bothers you.

Comment: Where I work, there are some conference rooms with boards plastered with confidential or security critical information. Quite possible that your interviewer was told "you can't use your webcam in this room when you are talking to a company outsider".

Answer (score 77):

I don't know if rude is the word I would use.  Suspicious comes to mind.

They certainly would have issues with you refusing to enable yours so to expect you to be ok with not seeing them seems one-sided at the very minimum.

If it were me, I wouldn't continue in the process for 2 reasons:

1. Jobs and interviews are a two-way street. You're interviewing them and they are not being as forthcoming as they expect you to do it.
2. They're hiding *something*. Whatever it is, there's something there they think will affect your decision or your interview.

**Don't work for someone you can't trust.**  Does this sound like you can trust them? Does it sound like they would trust you?

Comment: Maybe they want to avoid being discriminated by the interviewee :-)

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was getting at but couldn't think of how to phrase it. The interviewer could be handicapped or have a visual deformity or something. Or it could be a racial thing. Regardless, if you can't trust me enough to show me your face but expect to see mine, that's a deal-breaker for me.

Comment: Yeah I figured that was your point. In a way though, it would be the best case scenario here. This situation is indeed very suspicious

Answer (score 28):

Whether it's rude depends on why they didn't enable them.

If you didn't ask why, some possibilities (other than rudeness):

- Limited bandwidth, preferring to see you than have a bad connection

  - This is particularly true if multiple interviewers are connecting at once. I've been in this situation and as an interviewer, it's *really* annoying to deal with bandwidth issues resulting from streaming 3+ video feeds
- Lots of activity in the background (which might distract you)
- Lack of a webcamera (or an inconsistently working one)

  - We have lots of conference rooms with webcams. A lot of them don't work well and require setup time, as an interviewer I'd much rather interview *you* than fuss with a webcam
- Security regulations

It's possible it was rude. However, I would not automatically assume that, *especially* if you didn't ask them why they didn't enable them.

---

Rather amusingly, *today* only a few hours after writing this, I was involved in a virtual interview where we ended up not using my webcam because we were having system issues. Hopefully the candidate doesn't think it was rude, though given they were the source of the issues... :\  who knows.

Comment: No worries, it's' a hard thing to get used to. I'm guilty of misusing comments myself often. I've found that if you have a fundamental disagreement with an answer you can usually address that in your own answer which has the side benefit of it being more likely to be read by more people.

Comment: Another possible legitimate reason - security regulations. Many government organizations and contractors don't allow any photography or video on site except by approved individuals. Though if this were the case, I'm not sure why they would request a video interview to begin with.

Answer (score 18):

Personally, yes, I consider this very rude. The reason a video interview is used is to add extra sense of being personal by it being face to face (via video). Face to brick wall is not the same.

I might not have the same opinion if it was the person being interviewed as they are the one being invited to the situation, they may not have a camera.

With it being the interviewer who didn't want to switch their cam on (assuming they didn't make excuses that their camera has broken and they haven't been able to replace it) it makes you feel like you are being watched rather than it being a failed video chat. It should have been a phone interview if it wasn't a unknown technical problem.

Answer (score 8):

There are 2 root causes for this:

1. The webcam *didn't work*. If this is the case, then it isn't rude and shouldn't set alarm bells ringing
2. The webcam *does work*. This is rude, and may be indicative of scamming behaviour. Who would hide their identity in a job interview? *If* the interviewers contacted you initially, i.e. you didn't apply direct to a reputable company, then definitely sever ties with them